# What's the benefit to use Lyapunov stability analysis instead of checking the poles?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, stability-theory, linear-control

Assume that we have a dynamic system which is described in two forms:

$$G (s) = \frac {\text{num} (s)}{\text{den} (s)} $$

And

$$\dot {x} = Ax +Bu $$ $$ y =Cx +Du$$

Then we can find if the system is stable if we find the poles from:

$$0= \text{den} (s) $$

Or

$$\text{det} (sI-A) =0$$

If the polynomial has one or several positive roots, then it's unstable. So why should I use Lyapunov stability instead?

Comment: When you can look at poles, you should. Sometimes it is rather difficult, especially as your system gets larger and is nonlinear.

Comment: @SteveHeim Can you show me an example?

Comment: Just a remark: Consider using \text{} for operators (e.g. $\det$ ) and nonmathematical sysmbols (e.g. $\text{num}$, $\text{den}$ or text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different measures of stability for systems that develop over time. A couple of common ones are:

- [Lyapunov stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability)
- [Exponential stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_stability)
- [BIBO stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability)

If the system dynamics can be described as

$$
\matrix{\dot{x} = f(t, x, u) \\ y = h(t, x, u)} \tag{1}
$$

with $x$ the state vector of the system, $t$ time, $u$ the input of the system and $y$ the output of the system. Lyapunov stability essentially says that $(1)$ with $u=0$ is Lyapunov stable if $\|x\|$ remains bounded by a finite constant for all $t>t_0$. Exponential stability essentially says that $(1)$ with $u=0$ is exponential stable if $\|x\|$ remains bounded by some exponentially decaying function for all $t>t_0$. BIBO stability essentially says that $(1)$ with $u$ bounded by some constant and $x(t_0)=0$ is BIBO stable if $\|y\|$ is bounded by some other constant as well.

If a system satisfies a certain measure of stability, then that does not imply it would also satisfy the others as well. For example

$$
\matrix{
\dot{x} = u \\
y = x}
$$

is Lyapunov but not exponential or BIBO stable, while

$$
\matrix{
\dot{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} x + 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} u \\
y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} x
}
$$

is BIBO but not Lyapunov or exponential stable.

As MrYouMath mentioned these criteria can still be applied to for example nonlinear or time varying systems.

---

Also your statement: "If the polynomial has one or several positive roots, then it's unstable" is not entirely correct. For example the system with the transfer function $\frac{1}{s^2}$ is not stable according to any of the stability measures I mentioned in this answer.

Comment: So lyapunov equation is for analysing unstable systems?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Are you referring to [Lyapunov functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function) or [Lyapunov stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability) because those are related but different things?

Comment: I taking about lyapunov stability for state space models.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Then no, since as I stated in my answer a system can not be Lyapunov stable but still be BIBO stable. So not being Lyapunov stable does not mean unstable.

Comment: So what's the benifit by using lyapunov stability instead of checking the poles ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson For LTI systems there isn't really, since one often would deduce Lyapunov stability from these poles. Maybe for MIMO systems the poles by themselves wouldn't give information, since from that information alone you can't deduce the multiplicity (size of Jordan blocks in state space) of poles on the imaginary axis (if any of these Jordan blocks are of size bigger then one then the system is not Lyapunov stable).

Comment: so why are lyapunov stability so important in control theory?

Comment: So when should a use lyapunov stability and the equation $AX +AX^T = -Q $ which is the lyapunov equation for state space models.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Lyapunov stability is I think the most conservative definition of stability of passive systems (a system with no inputs, or a fixed state dependent control law) which can also be applied to nonlinear or time varying systems. So you don't need a different definition of stability  when dealing with a different type of dynamics. Only proving that any of those systems is Lyapunov stable might require a different technique.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson That Lyapunov equation for state space models allows you to find a Lyapunov function, so as stated before is not exactly the same as Lyapunov stability. For a normal LTI system a Lyapunov function is not that extremely useful, but if it based on a linearisation of an equilibrium point of a nonlinear system then that Lyapunov function can give you a lower bound of the basin of attraction of that equilibrium point.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Another application of that Lyapunov equation is when you are dealing with switched linear systems. Namely if you are able to find a common quadratic Lyapunov function, then under arbitrary switching the system will remain asymptotically stable.

Comment: Can you show med how I can use lyapunov on a lineraized state space model and find a conclusion of that?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson if you have a nonlinear system of the form $\dot{x}=f(x)$ and linearize at a stable equilibrium point $\Delta\dot{x}=A\,\Delta x$, then you can find a Lyapunov function by solving the Lyapunov equation ($V(x)=x^\top X\,x$) which will show a lower bound of the basin on attraction of that equilibrium point by looking at the largest compact set for which $\dot{V}(x)$ is negative definite (while using the nonlinear dynamics).

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand, but I take your post as lyapunov function is very good to find stability of nonlinear system who has been linearized?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson No! I was only trying to say that a Lyapunov function based on solving the Lyapunov equation from the linearized model can be used to estimate the region around the linearized equilibrium point, which would converge to that point. Lyapunov stability is only one of many ways of defining stability in general.

Comment: But I can use lyapunov to find stability points at the nonlinear model ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson What do you mean by stability points? Equilibria which are locally asymptotically stable?

Comment: Stability equilibrium locations i mean. Lyapynov's method is to find which states interval is stable and which state intervals are not stable?

Answer (score 1):

The poles of a system are only defined for linear time-invariant (LTI) system. There are examples of linear time-variant (LTV) systems that have negative eigenvalues but still are unstable, hence the usage of eigenvalues for stability analysis is not possible for even LTV systems.

That means if you want to study the stability of LTV or nonlinear systems in order to design nonlinear controllers or use linear controllers for nonlinear plants then a very common method is to use Lyapunov functions.

Additionally to the advantage that Lyapunov's direct method is a general method for stability analysis it can also be used for linear control design for nonlinear plants. By using Lyapunov functions it is possible to estimate the region of attraction for an equilibrium point. Hence, it is possible to estimate the region in which the linearized model is still appropriate to describe the dynamics of the nonlinear system.

As an example look at

$$(1)\qquad \dot{x} = -x^3$$
$$(2)\qquad \dot{x} = +x^3$$

it is not possible to draw any conclusions by linearizing the systems at the equilibrium point $x=0$ as this results in the linearized system

$$\Delta \dot{x}=0$$

in both cases.

By using the Lyapunov function (which is positive definite and radially unbounded)

$$V(x)=x^2 \implies \dot{V}=2x\dot{x}$$

$$(1)\qquad \dot{V}=-2x^4<0$$
$$(2)\qquad \dot{V}=+2x^4>0.$$

By using this Lyapunov function we showed that the origin of (1) is globally asymptotically stable and the origin of (2) is unstable.